# Google BigQuery support for Avro logicalTypes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

As Google claims there is no support for conversion from Avro `logicalType` to BigQuery specific type (as described [here on the bottom](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro)).

However I'm able to load Avro file with the following schema:

```
schema = {
    'name': 'test',
    'namespace': 'testing',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'test_timestamp', 'type': 'long', 'logicalType': 'timestamp-millis'},
    ],
}
```

onto BigQuery with column of type **TIMESTAMP**.

The situation is different with the following schema:

```
schema = {
    'name': 'test',
    'namespace': 'testing',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'testdate', 'type': 'int', 'logicalType': 'date'},
    ],
}
```

and BigQuery table with column of type **DATE**. I was using bq load in the following way (in both cases):

```
bq --location=EU load --source_format=AVRO --project_id=test-project dataset.table "gs://bucket/test_file.avro"
```

and it failed with exception:

```
Field testdate has changed type from DATE to INTEGER
```

Is there any chance that `logicalTypes` will be supported by BigQuery or is there any elegant way to workaround such situation? (I'm aware of workaround where temporary table is used and then there is BQL select that casts TIMESTAMPS to DATES but it's not really pretty :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native understanding for Avro Logical Types is now available publicly for all BigQuery users. Please refer to the documentation page here for more details: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types

Comment: Just want to update that the API change is rolled out and that customers can now use the useAvroLogicalTypes load job config flag to optionally enable it per load job, without needing to be whitelisted. I'm updating the documentation but you can find it in the API discovery page (https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest).

Customers can also set this to false for all their Avro load jobs if they believe they will be negatively impacted once this is turned on by default.